# M1 How to know what contents corresponding to layout / block / template?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, template

Currently, I don't know how to find the layout of the manage customer page (`Customers > Manage Customer`).
Generally, how can I find the `block/layout/template/controller` of a specific page?

Thank you!

(PS: please tell me why I can't say hello at first line of my post :( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mage/Adminhtml` module is responsible for backend functionality. Here you can find Controller & block related to each module in backend.

For Customer block, you can refer in `Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/`.

For Backend layout & template, you can check on below two paths:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/
```

To find out which block is coming in use for particular page, You need to check particular layout file. For example to check `Manage Customer` page block, first you need to refer `customer.xml` file on below path:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/customer.xml
```

In the layout file, we need to check as per handle which block is loading like below section:

```
<adminhtml_customer_grid>
<block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
    <block type="adminhtml/customer_grid" name="admin.customer.grid"/>
</block>
</adminhtml_customer_grid>
```

Comment: Ooh okay, so we need to check the layout to find blocks and config.xml to find layout , ok i understand. Another question, there is a debugger for Magento 1 like the Drupal Twig debugger ?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable a template path hints for admin

> System > Configuration > Developer > Debug

Select `Yes` to **`Template Path hints`** and **`Add Block names to hints`**

You can get the controller from the Url.

**Hope it Helps.**